# Change all values of a column in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a panda data frame that contains values of a column like '01:00'. I want to deduct 1 from it means '01:00' will be '00:00'. Can anyone helps

Comment: Do you mean if it is "02:00" changed value should be "01:00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`timedeltas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['01:00', '02:00', '24:00']})

df['new'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'] + ':00') - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='h')
df['new'] = df['new'].astype(str).str[-18:-13]

print (df)
     col    sub
0  01:00  00:00
1  02:00  01:00
2  24:00  23:00
```

Another faster solution by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) if format of all `string`s is `01:00` to `24:00`:

```
L = ['{:02d}:00'.format(x) for x in range(25)]
d = dict(zip(L[1:], L[:-1]))

df['new'] = df['col'].map(d)
print (df)
     col    new
0  01:00  00:00
1  02:00  01:00
2  24:00  23:00
```

Comment: @jazrael it return Timedelta object with value like 0 days 00:00:00 can you convert it in str like '00:00'

Comment: I wouldnt use `sub` as col_name because of `df` built in method sub (i.e. if eventually do `df.sub`, this can be ambiguous)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want to do is subtract an hour from the time which is stored in your dataframe as a string. You can do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
subtract_one_hour = lambda x: (datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M') - timedelta(hours=1)).strftime("%H:%M")
df['minus_one_hour'] = df['original_time'].apply(subtract_one_hour)
```

Comment: ValueError: time data '24:00' does not match format '%H:%M'

Comment: Does your data represent time? If so, you should convert '24:00' to '00:00' first.